# Chart.js configuration

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have a bar chart created in chart.js and its config is below:

```js
import Chart from 'chart.js/auto';

document.addEventListener("turbo:load", function(e) {
  let manufacturersPieChartCanvas = document.getElementById('manufacturers-pie-chart');

  if (manufacturersPieChartCanvas) {
    let labels = JSON.parse(manufacturersPieChartCanvas.dataset.manufacturers_chart_labels);
    let data = JSON.parse(manufacturersPieChartCanvas.dataset.manufacturers_chart_data);

    const config = {
      type: 'bar',
      data: {
        labels: labels,
        datasets: [{
          backgroundColor: ['yellow', 'red', 'green', 'blue'],
          data: data,
          hoverOffset: 4
        }]
      },
      options: {
        responsive: true,
        categoryPercentage: 1,
        barPercentage: 0.8,
        scaleShowValues: false,
        indexAxis: 'y',
        scales: {
          yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
              autoSkip: false
            }
          }]
        }
      }
    };

    let manufacturersPieChart = new Chart(
      manufacturersPieChartCanvas,
      config
    );
  }
})
```

A portion of it looks like so:

[image]

I am trying to allow ALL the bar titles to show up.  I have followed suggestions on SO, in regards to autoSkip false but they don't seem to have any effect.  For this chart, it is imperative that all bar titles display all the time.  Also, i'd prefer the height to be increased to make each bar slightly thicker.  I have tried with config options and can make them thicker but the overall chart area doesn't increase to accommodate them?

Any suggestions to fix these issues?

Thanks.

Comment: I would provide the whole code that builds the chart. Meaning the labels that are not provided and any other element that might be missing to reproduce the chart

Comment: @rustyBucketBay Code updated but i'm unsure it will make much difference to be honest. I posted the part that was most important.  If the graph is a vertical bar chart then all the labels do show but I basically want thicker bars, all labels and a slightly taller chart area to house it all.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to define your scales in V2 syntax while using V3, I advise reading the [migration guide](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/getting-started/v3-migration.html) first if you are transfering from V2.

To make the bars a bit thicker you can increase the `barPercentage` and `categoryPercentage` to 1 but this will remove all the space between the bars. The only other option to make them bigger is by giving the chart actually more space by making the canvas bigger using CSS

```js
var options = {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        backgroundColor: 'pink',
        barPercentage: 1,
        categoryPercentage: 1
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        backgroundColor: 'orange',
        barPercentage: 1,
        categoryPercentage: 1
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    indexAxis: 'y',
    scales: {
      y: {
        ticks: {
          autoSkip: false
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.5.1/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: What is setting the existing chart height? I have no CSS specifying it.  I'd like it to size itself but the default height is too small.